# How to take screenshot in aws device farm for android espresso testing

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-espresso, aws-device-farm

I am using `aws` device farm for running my android tests, and we are using espresso framework. Some of the tests are failing today, and I want to take screenshots if my test fails. I have gone through your documentation but couldn't find anything concrete. This is what I know so far:

[Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-uiautomator.html#test-types-android-uiautomator-screenshots)

> You can take screenshots as part of your Android UI Automator tests.
>
> To take a screenshot, call the takeScreenshot method (for example, takeScreenshot("/sdcard/uiautomator-screenshots/home-screen-1234.png");).
>
> Note: All screenshots must be stored in the `/sdcard/uiautomator-screenshots directory`. You must specify the full path (including the file name) of the screenshot to be stored.
>       The `takeScreenshot` method works for API Levels 17 and higher only. For API Level 16, UI Automator is supported, but screenshots are not supported.

Is there any way I can configure `aws device` farm to take screenshots automatically without calling the function in test? Is it supported? Also, I couldn't find any screenshot related [commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/index.html#cli-aws-devicefarm). I will really appreciate if someone could explain the steps required to screenshot. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am a developer working on AWS Device Farm.

That bit of documentation about the `takeScreenshot` method is for *uiautomator 1.0*, not *uiautomator 2.0* which works in conjunction with Android Instrumentation/Espresso.

I don't believe Espresso has added built-in functionality for capturing screenshots. However, if you take a look at the official AWS Device Farm Sample App for Android, there is a helper class [ScreenShot.java](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/amazonaws/devicefarm/android/referenceapp/Util/ScreenShot.java) that you should be able to use directly from your Espresso tests.

Hope that helps!

Best,
Andrew @ AWS Device Farm

Comment: I have posted here, can you please help me to resolve this issue also.